# SQL Server Express backup restore not working for asp.net membership

Tags: asp.net-membership, backup, sql-server-express

I am backing up a SQL Server Express database and then restoring on another machine. For some reason the asp.net membership data is not getting transferred. Do I need to do something different. Does ASP.NET membership data not get backed up?

Comment: **WHAT** exactly are you backing up and restoring?? Which database(s)?

Answer (score 2):

So you're not using the default aspnetdb? The membership tables are contained in your database? These would be have names with the prefix `aspnet_`. Perhaps you also need to back up aspnetdb?